# 1 Dimensional ODE with solution in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

For part of a bigger question, I need either a solution or a counterexample to the following 1 dimensional ODE.

Let $h\in L^2(0,\infty)$ (complex valued functions) and $r \in (0,\infty)$. Under boundary conditions $w(0) = c_1a + c_2$ and $w'(0) = c_3a + c_4$ where the $c_i$ are complex constants and $a$ is a complex parameter, is there an $a \in \mathbb{C}$ for which there is a solution in $H^2(0,\infty)$ for:

$$w''(t) = irw(t) - h(t) \ \ \ (t\in (0,\infty))?$$

The strange boundary conditions are just my way of saying that there is one parameter I want to solve for if a solution exists in order to couple this ODE with another one on the negative real line.

If I use Laplace transforms, this is equivalent to asking if there exists $w \in H^2(0,\infty)$ such that

$$\hat{w} = \frac{\hat{h}}{ir-s^2} - \frac{w(0)+sw'(0)}{ir - s^2}.$$

There is a solution to this ODE by taking the inverse Laplace transform of the above equation, namely
$$ w(t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{ir}}\int_0^t h(u)\sinh(\sqrt{ir}(t-u))du + \frac{w(0)}{\sqrt{ir}}\sinh(\sqrt{ir}t) + w'(0)\cosh(\sqrt{ir}t).$$

However, this is not obvious to me whether or not there is an $a$ for which it's in $L^2(0,\infty)$. Is there another solution to this ODE that is in $L^2(0,\infty)$ or if not, is there an explicit counterexample? In other words, given $h\in L^2(0,\infty)$, are there nonhomogeneous boundary conditions of the form aforementioned that give me a solutions $w\in H^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: It's true if $h = 0$.

Comment: Please check your email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **1. Consider the homogeneous case, i.e., $h=0$.**

The two linearly independent solutions are $e^{\pm \sqrt{ir} t}$, where we take the principle branch cut of $\sqrt\cdot$. In order to make the solution $L^2[0,\infty)$, you need to discard the exponentially growing solution $e^{\sqrt{ir} t}$ and keep only the decaying one $e^{-\sqrt{ir} t}$. So $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ can not be used alone but only in equal weight pair in each of your terms. Explicitly 
$$w(t)=w(0)e^{-\sqrt{ir} t},$$
and $w'(0)=-w(0)\sqrt{ir}$. Substitute in the linear form of $w(0)$ and $w'(0)$, we can easily obtain the condition on $a$ which is $a=-\frac{c_1\sqrt{ir}+c_3}{c_2\sqrt{ir}+c_4}$ if the denominator does not vanish, and any $a\in\Bbb C$ if both the denominator and numerator vanish, and does not exist if only the denominator vanishes.

> **2. Now consider the inhomogeneous case but with homogeneous boundary condition, i.e., $h\not\equiv0$ and $w(0)=w'(0)=0$.**

There are two interesting cases for two different Green's functions. The difference of these two Green's function is a homogeneous solution.

2.1 The first Green's function is $$G_1(t)=\frac1{k}\sinh(kt)\Theta(t)$$

where $k=\sqrt{ir}$ and $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function.
$$w(t)=-\int_0^t h(u)G_1(t-u)du.$$
There are many $h$'s (counterexamples saught by the OP) making $w\notin L^2[0,\infty)$ for $G_1$: (1) $h(t)=e^{-at}\in L^2[0,\infty)$ with some positive $a$; (2) any $h\in C[0,\infty)$ compactly supported and positive on $(0,T)$ for some positive $T$.

For $G_1$, to produce $w\in L^2[0,\infty)$ with a nonzero $h\in L^2[0,\infty)\cap C[0,\infty)$, both the real part and imaginary part of $h$ have to alternate their signs over $t\in[0,\infty)$.

2.2 The second Green's function is 
$$G_2(t)=-\frac1{2k}e^{-k|t|}.$$
Then
$$w(t)=-\int_0^\infty h(u)G_2(t-u)du+\int_0^\infty h(u)G_2(-u)du=-h*G_2+(h*G_2)(t=0),$$
where $*$ stands for convolution. The second term is to ensure the null initial condition. $G_2\in L^1[0,\infty)$. By [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality#Euclidean_Space), 
$$\|h*G\|_2\le \|h\|_2\|G_2\|_1,$$
and $w\in L^2[0,\infty),\, \forall h\in L^2[0,\infty)$.

Note: As indicated before, $G_1-G_2=\frac{e^{kt}}k$ a solution of the homogeneous equation.

Separating out the "explosive" exponentially growing term $e^{kt}$ from $\sinh(kt)$ of $G_1(t)$, we have the following proposition regarding the square integrability of $w$.

> **3. Proposition 1.: $\forall k\in\Bbb C\,\ni \mathbf{Re}(k)>0 \implies \exists h\in L^2[0,\infty) \ni \big(w[h,a](t):=\int_0^t h(u)e^{k(t-u)}\,du-ae^{kt}\notin L^2[0,\infty),\, \forall a\in\Bbb C-\{0\} \big).$**

Proof: Take the Laplace transformation of $w[h,a]$ 
\begin{align}
\mathscr L[w]&=\mathscr L[h]\mathscr L[e^{kt}]-a\mathscr L[e^{kt}], \tag1\\
\mathscr L[e^{kt}](s)&=\frac1{s-k}.
\end{align}
$\mathscr L[h]\in H^{2+}$ the Hardy function space on the right half complex plane iff $h\in L^2[0,\infty)$. Let 
$$\mathscr L[h](s)=\frac{s-k}{(s+\alpha)(s+\beta)},$$
or equivalently
$$h(t)=\frac{(\beta+k)e^{-\beta t}-(\alpha+k)e^{-\alpha t}}{\beta-\alpha},\tag2$$
for some $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C$ where $\mathbf{Re}(\alpha)>0,\mathbf{Re}(\beta)>0$. $\mathscr L[h]\in H^{2+}$ since  it is a proper fractional function and its poles are all in the left half complex plane. By Eq. (1), there is always a simple pole at $k$ in the right half complex plane so long as $a\ne0$. Then $\mathscr L\big[w[h,a]\big]\notin H^{2+}$ and $w[h,a]\notin L^2[0,\infty),\,\forall a\ne0$. This can also be verified by direct computation of $w$ with the chosen $h$ with the explicit expression Eq. (2). $\quad\square$

> **4. Proposition 2: $$k\in\Bbb C\,\ni \mathbf{Re}(k)>0, h\in L^2[0,\infty) \implies \exists !a\in\Bbb C \ni \big(w[a](t):=\int_0^t h(u)e^{k(t-u)}\,du-ae^{kt}\in L^2[0,\infty)\big).$$**

Proof: Take the Laplace transformation of $w[h,a]$ 
\begin{align}
\mathscr L[w]&=\mathscr L[h]\mathscr L[e^{kt}]-a\mathscr L[e^{kt}], \tag1\\
\mathscr L[e^{kt}](s)&=\frac1{s-k}.
\end{align}
$\mathscr L[h]\in H^{2+}$ the Hardy function space on the right half complex plane iff $h\in L^2[0,\infty)$. Let $D(\omega;R)$ be the closed disk centered at $\omega$ and radius $0<R<\mathbf{Re}(k)$. For an arbitrary $x\ge 0$, let $\Omega_x:=\{x+iy\}\setminus D(\omega-k,R)$. We consider two cases.

(1)$k$ is not one of the zeros.

$$\frac{\mathscr L[h]}{s-k}=\frac{\mathscr L[h](s)-\mathscr L[h](k)}{s-k}+\frac{\mathscr L[h](k)}{s-k}$$
$\phi(s):=\frac{\mathscr L[h](s)-\mathscr L[h](k)}{s-k}$. $\phi(s)$ is holomorphic on the closed right half complex plane.

We will prove that $\phi(s)$ is square integrable and uniformly bounded along all vertical line on the right hand side complex plane. $|\phi(s)|$ has a maximum on the compact $D(k,R)$.

$$|\phi(s)|^2\le \frac{|\mathscr L[h](s)|^2}{R^2}+\frac{|\mathscr L[h](k)|^2}{|s-k|^2},\ \forall |s-k|\ge R.$$
We have
$$\int_{\Omega_x} |\phi(x+iy)|^2 dy\le \frac1{R^2}\int_{\Omega_x} |\mathscr L[h](x+iy)|^2dy+\frac{\pi |\mathscr L[h](k)|^2}{2\,\max(x,R)}.$$
The integral on the right hand side is bounded uniformly over all $x\ge0$ as $\mathscr L[h]\in H^{2+}$. So now too is the left hand side. We conclude $\phi\in H^{2+}$.

Then setting and only setting $a=\mathscr L[h](k)$ leads to the desired result.

(2) $k$ is one of the zeros.

$\phi(s):=\frac{\mathscr L[h](s)}{s-k}$.  $\frac{\mathscr L[h]}{s-k}\in H^{2+}$. Again $\phi$ is holomorphic on $B(k;R)$.

We will prove that $\phi(s)$ is square integrable and uniformly bounded along all vertical line on the right hand side complex plane. $|\phi(s)|$ has a maximum on the compact $D(k,R)$.
$$\int_{\Omega_x} |\phi(x+iy)|^2 dy\le \frac1{R^2}\int_{\Omega_x} |\mathscr L[h](x+iy)|^2dy.$$
The integral on the right hand side is bounded uniformly over all $x\ge0$ as $\mathscr L[h]\in H^{2+}$. Then so is the left hand side. We conclude $\phi\in H^{2+}$.

Setting and only setting $a=0$ leads to the desired result.

$\quad\square$

Comment: Why is my solution wrong form wrong? When $h=0$, the form is correct, you just weight the coefficients so that the "positive" exponential term vanishes. You can rewrite it in terms of exponentials if you want, though it makes the form no more 'right' than it currently already is. For certain cases of $h$, such as if $h$ is a certain exponential, you need the "positive" exponential term to achieve cancellation from the convolution. The form is fine, and this answer tells me nothing, sorry. I want to know about when $h$ is not zero. Grateful for any help! :)

Comment: @abe.nong: For $h=0$, your current form gives the impression $w(0)$ and $w′(0)$ are independent. They are not, but $w′(0)=−\sqrt{ir}w′(0)$ if they the solution is to be square integrable. Under this condition, it is much clearer to (after substituting in the previous equation) write it in a single term of exponential $e^{−\sqrt{ir}t}$ instead of two terms of hyperbolic. You also have a typo switching $w(0)$ and $w′(0)$. Now I have added the solution for $h\ne0$. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and answer. I am not interested in the case where I have 0 boundary condition, sorry. In that case, it's well known that the spectrum of the Laplacian is $(-\infty,0]$, hence there is always a solution for $irw - w'' = h$ for any $h\in L^2(0,\infty)$. My question has been, and remains to be, whether I can say something when we are not in a trivial scenario. In my original question, the strange boundary conditions with one parameter are there to couple this ODE with another. I can't do that if I have 0 boundary conditions, as that's not solvable for one parameter.

Comment: Perhaps I can clarify what I would like to know: Given $h \in L^2(0,\infty)$, are there nonhomogeneous boundary conditions of the form aforementioned that give me a solutions $w \in H^2(0,\infty)$? That is, a value for the parameter $a$ that gives me a square integrable solution?

Comment: AH i'm seeing something that might help me. Your second Green's function is really helpful. If it all works out, I'll verify your answer ASAP. Otherwise I might have some follow up questions for you/lay out my thinking in a separate answer for you to comment on.

Comment: @abe.nong: My point for using the zero boundary condition for the nonzero source ODE is that you can always manipulate the zero source ODE to fit the nonzero boundary condition since the ODE is linear. With your $G_1$ the set of $h$ producing a square integrable solution is small, whilst with my $G_2$, you can always find a square integrable solution for every square integrable $h$ and it is easy to find the condition for $a$ just like what I have demonstrated in Section 1. of my answer. I will think further about the details though when I get some time.

Comment: @abe.nong:  Moreoer, $G_2$ is the reason for your statement about the spectrum of the Laplacian (actually more appropriately the Helmholz equation) to hold, not $G_1$.

Comment: I believe I can us the homogeneous term with the negative exponential to get what I need. Thank you so very much! :) I'll verify everything works in the next few days and accept your answer.

Comment: @abe.nong: I suppose by "homogeneous term with the negative exponential" you are talking about the negative exponential formula for the homogeneous ODE where h=0 in my Section 1? Now if $t$ is indeed time and this is some kind of signal response problem, then the Green's function has to vanish for $t<0$ lest it responds to the future of the signal. Then $G_1$ has to be used. I added a general proposition for counterexamples as Section 3, separating out the main explosive positive exponential term from $\sinh$. Check it out. Also, you are welcome. I am glad to have helped. :-)

Comment: @abe.nong: I have added Section 4. Proposition 2. for a general result. Check it out. This is a great problem. I have learnt a lot, too,  through solving it.

Comment: Hans, is there someway I can contact you privately for your proper name? I'm happy to put my email up for a short period of time if you want to email me. I'd just like to be able to thank/acknowledge you properly for giving me the necessary Green's function IF this piece of the puzzle you've provided me manages to lead anywhere (no guarantee that it will be able to go anywhere substantial at all).

Comment: @abe.nong: Yes, if you would put your email address up, I will email you. You are very kind, indeed. Also, I am curious as to which Green's function you find useful, $G_1$ or $G_2$ and why? Do you find Proposition 2 and 1 useful?